# Gracefully handle a failed lazy symbol binding in C?

Tags: c, bash, shared-libraries

In short, I am looking for a way of handling this without the process crashing:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _evalstring
  Referenced from: /Users/nrser/src/gh/nrser/my_first_ext/ext/my_first_ext/my_first_ext.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _evalstring
  Referenced from: /Users/nrser/src/gh/nrser/my_first_ext/ext/my_first_ext/my_first_ext.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

./bin/console: line 2: 69989 Abort trap: 6           bundle exec pry -f -r my_first_ext
```

Is there a way to tell if `evalstring` is present before making the call, or trap the error in the function and return something else?

So far the resources I've been able to find focus on stopping the error form happening, not handling it when it does.

For context, I have a some C that runs both inside a Bash "loadable", where Bash's `evalstring` is available, and also outside of it, where `evalstring` is not.

It is an error to call functions that depend on `evalstring` unless inside the loadable, but I'd rather do something nicer than crash the process if users do.

### Details

The `evalstring` function is declared as

```
extern int evalstring __P((char *, const char *, int));
```

in `<BASH_DIR>/include/bash/builtins/common.h`, at least as far as what my IDE thinks.

I understand that portability may be an issue. I'm targeting Linux and macOS/OSX at this time.

Answer (score 1):

At least on Linux the only way to achieve this is to provide your own wrapper which intercepts calls to `evalstring` and then redirects them to actual implementation obtained via `dlsym` or fails in app-specific way. Such wrappers can be implemented manually or (if you need to achieve this for all functions in some library) via script (for example see [Implib.so wrapper generator](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so)).

Comment: Thanks, I'm really looking for how to detect if the function _is_ present or not (at runtime, since the lazy binding is obviously happening at runtime)

Comment: @nrser You can just check if result of `dlsym` is `NULL`.

Comment: Do you mean `dlsym( NULL, "evalstring")`, which from my understanding will check the main program? EDIT: Yup, that worked! Awesome, thanks so much.

Comment: Ok, that `dlsym( NULL, "evalstring" )` is not working as expected - it's returning `NULL` both inside and outside the `bash` process :/

Comment: I tried going the other way around and setting a flag when I'm loading from inside `bash` via the loadable and bailing out of functions when the flag is false, but it seems that loading the shared object fails even if the dynamically bound variables are never used. Not sure if I'm searching wrong, but it's been really hard to find informations on.... not much on what to do when an `extern` variable is not actually present and isn't going to be.